# How to avoid overlapping tr values in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have a table compiled with data and am having positioning problems with overlapping rows and styling properties. I have tried tweaking the CSS but nothing really worked.

below is my HTML table

```
<table class="ui-widget" id="lines">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Line Item Number</th>
        <th>Line Item Date</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Number of Units</th>
        <th>Line Item Total</th>
        <th>Task Code</th>
        <th>Expense Code</th>
        <th>Timekeeper ID</th>
        <th>Line Item Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="errortrue">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20150301</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>E1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="9" class="error">           
          Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE<br/>
          Line : 1 MATTER NAME is a required field<br/>
          Line : 1 BILLING END DATE is a required field<br/>
          Line : 1 INVOICE DATE is a required field<br/>
          Line : 1 BILLING START DATE is a required field<br/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="errortrue">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20150304</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>E2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="error">               
              Line : 2 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="errortrue">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20150306</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>T3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="error">
              Line : 3 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    td error { color: red; font-size: 100%;} 
    tr.errortrue { color: #c33; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;} 
    table.lines th { background-color : grey;  color: white; padding: 5px;}
    table {empty-cells: show; border-collapse: collapse; }
    table.lines td { text-align: center;}
    table.header { float: left;  }
    table.header th { text-align: left; }
    table.header td{ text-align: right; }
    table.header td.right{ text-align: left; }
    table.header tfoot th { text-align: left; background: #ebebeb}
    table.header tfoot td { text-align: right; background: #ebebeb}
    td.right, th.right { text-align: right; }
 </style>
```

Here are the snapshots of CSS in Chrome

**Invoice Line Items Table CSS**
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6hfX.png

**tr css**
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwK6.png

I am a beginner at CSS. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I am guessing the error class has some positioning on it

Comment: makes no sense to have display: table-row on a table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaesuygf/) I noticed you are assigning a class to the id lines in your css when it should be and id. Example you have `table.lines th` which should really be `table#lines th` unless you change in your html `<table class="ui-widget" id="lines">` to `<table class="ui-widget" class="lines">`

CSS:

```
table#lines td.error {
color: red;
font-size: 100%;
text-align:left;
padding-left:15px;
}
th {
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
}
td {
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
}
tr.errortrue {
color: #c33;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
}
table#lines th {
background-color : grey;
color: white;
padding: 5px;
}
table {
empty-cells: show;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table#lines td {
text-align: center;
}
.align-left {
text-align:left;
}
table.header {
float: left;
}
table.header th {
text-align: left;
}
table.header td {
text-align: right;
}
table.header td.right {
text-align: left;
}
table.header tfoot th {
text-align: left;
background: #ebebeb
}
table.header tfoot td {
text-align: right;
background: #ebebeb
}
td.right, th.right {
text-align: right;
}
```

I applied some changes to this fiddle which may be what you are looking for. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this css

```
th {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
td {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Manipulate it the way you want. here is the jfiddle link. Good luck. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/avttkdst/2/